# Why importing statement "from package.module import class" is not working?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have the following project structure:

```
Package\
|______ src\
|_______|___ __init__.py
|       |___ Module_1.py
|       |___ Module_2.py
|       |
|       |___ Module_3\
|            |_________ __init__.py
|            |_________ Module_3.py
|            |_________ assets\
|
|______ setup.py
|______ __init__.py
```

I'm trying to import one class from Module_3 using:

```
from Package.Module_3 import SomeClass
```

However, i'm getting: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Package.Module_3'`

`Package/__init__.py` file has the following import statements:

```
from .src import Module_1, Module_2, Module_3
from .src.Module_3 import Module_3
```

`Package/src/__init__.py` and `Package/src/Module_3/__init__.py` files are empty. Am I missing some extra import statement in some of my `__init__.py` files to fix my import error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You really don't want to structure the project this way - because if you distribute the `src` folder as a package, the top-level `Package` will be missing, and if you distribute the entire thing as a folder, if it can work at all, you'll need to explicitly exclude `setup.py` from the installed package (since it isn't actually part of what's supposed to get installed). (Also, `setup.py` based approaches are on the way out, in favour of `pyproject.toml`.) Please read https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ to see how it normally works.

Comment: from src.Module_3 import some_function should work fine

Comment: Yes, that import statement works well, but is it possible to avoid the "src" in the import statement?
Import statements like "from Package import Module_1", "from Package import Module_3" works, but "import Package.Module_1" is not working...